# Модальное окно без кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Подключил Bootstrap и пытаюсь создать модальное окно без клика на кнопку
То есть я просто захожу на любую страницу а модальное окно сразу открывается

Вставил нижний код так модальное окно стало не отображаться

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно присвоить модулю id (например myModal) и добавить этот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Или без Javascript можно добавить класс `show` вот так `class="modal show"`, но тогда будет проблема с закрытием модуля

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233550/launch-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```html
<div class="user-profile" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Кликни на меня</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Текст</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  Текст
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Закрыть</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```